# How to get row number in callback function without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I'm freshman in javascript and try to understand more internal things.

I have some code on pure js. I build on page list of users what I got from JS array. And I try to make button delete user which gonna send list number where it pressed in callback function.

HTML

```
<div id="userTable"></div>
```

JS

```
var users = [
  {name: "Andrew"},
  {name: "Bob"},
  {name: "Ololo"}
];

function usersController(){
    usersView("userTable", users, {
        onDel: function(user){
            alert(user);
            //user.push({"name":"123"});
        }
    });
}

function usersView(selector, user, callback){
    ele = document.getElementById(selector);
    ele.innerHTML = "";
    var li, input;
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    for (x in user){
        li = document.createElement('li');
        input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "button";
        input.value = "Remove";
        //input.onclick = function(){alert(x);};
        input.addEventListener("click", function(){callback.onDel(x);});
        li.innerHTML = user[x].name;
        li.appendChild(input); 
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    ele.appendChild(ul);
}
```

Problems what I got whatever button I pressed get last number of list(2) all the time. Can I do that without jQuery and what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the callback function is called, it takes the then-current value of `x` from the closure. Which will be 1. The simplest solution will be to replace this loop

```
    for (x in user){
```

with one using `let` (taking advantage of its block scope), like

```
for (let x of user) {
```